# Is using loudspeaker &microphone for giving azan is allowed in islam?

Tags: practical-islam, adhan

Is using  loudspeaker +microphone for giving azan is allowed in islam?Is there any proof of it given in quran that microphone and loudspeakers can't be used in azan???

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: The qur'an was revealed 14 centuries ago, and when we're loudspeakers and microphones invented? Please explain what you mean by proof given in qur'an!